# Issue Too many redirect after upgrade tomcat to 9.0.71

Tags: tomcat, spring-security

Actually, we are upgrading our tomcat to 9.0.71, we have a issue when after login some application show too many redirects but at the end the app load the page, we try to figure out what could be the reason of this behavior but is not clear.

We use spring security and Java 17. we have apache HTTP front end behind and F5 load balancer, the tomcat use AJP to communicate with Apache HTTP.

are ther some special features in tomcat will modify the behavior of my app

thanks

We test with tomcat 9.0.50 and the issue does not happen. then we try with tomcat 9.053 and the issue appear.

We trye to do a debug of spring security, but we only see one redirect to login opage but is not clear what cause this

are there some special features in tomcat will modify the behavior of requests to the app. what  could be the cause or how can validate what

thanks
this the Logs

```
org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession     (189) - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (109) - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation    (210) - Authorized filter invocation [GET /comunes/javascript/funcionesGenerales.js] with attributes [permitAll]
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter      (333) - Secured GET /comunes/javascript/funcionesGenerales.js
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (120) - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal      (218) - Securing GET /comunes/javascript/prototype.js
 org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession    (189) - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal      (218) - Securing GET /comunes/javascript/window.js
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (109) - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession    (189) - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal      (218) - Securing GET /comunes/javascript/ajax.js
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (109) - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession    (189) - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation    (210) - Authorized filter invocation [GET /comunes/javascript/prototype.js] with attributes [permitAll]
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation    (210) - Authorized filter invocation [GET /comunes/javascript/window.js] with attributes [permitAll]
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (109) - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter      (333) - Secured GET /comunes/javascript/prototype.js
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter      (333) - Secured GET /comunes/javascript/window.js
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation    (210) - Authorized filter invocation [GET /comunes/javascript/ajax.js] with attributes [permitAll]
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter      (333) - Secured GET /comunes/javascript/ajax.js
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (120) - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (120) - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (120) - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal      (218) - Securing GET /comunes/estilos/default.css
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal      (218) - Securing GET /comunes/estilos/appname.css
 org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession    (189) - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession    (189) - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (109) - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (109) - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation    (210) - Authorized filter invocation [GET /comunes/estilos/default.css] with attributes [permitAll]
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation    (210) - Authorized filter invocation [GET /comunes/estilos/appname.css] with attributes [permitAll]
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter      (333) - Secured GET /comunes/estilos/default.css
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter      (333) - Secured GET /comunes/estilos/appname.css
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (120) - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (120) - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal      (218) - Securing GET /comunes/estilos/alert.css
 org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession    (189) - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (109) - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation    (210) - Authorized filter invocation [GET /comunes/estilos/alert.css] with attributes [permitAll]
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter      (333) - Secured GET /comunes/estilos/alert.css
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (120) - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal      (218) - Securing GET /faces/asset/img/TULogo-blue.png
 org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession    (189) - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (109) - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal      (218) - Securing GET /comunes/imagenes/btn_imprimr.png
 org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession    (189) - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (109) - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation    (210) - Authorized filter invocation [GET /faces/asset/img/TULogo-blue.png] with attributes [authenticated]
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter      (333) - Secured GET /faces/asset/img/TULogo-blue.png
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation    (210) - Authorized filter invocation [GET /comunes/imagenes/btn_imprimr.png] with attributes [permitAll]
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter      (333) - Secured GET /comunes/imagenes/btn_imprimr.png
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (120) - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal      (218) - Securing GET /comunes/imagenes/TruVision-Informacion-Comercial-76.png
 org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession    (189) - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (109) - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation    (210) - Authorized filter invocation [GET /comunes/imagenes/TruVision-Informacion-Comercial-76.png] with attributes [permitAll]
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter      (333) - Secured GET /comunes/imagenes/TruVision-Informacion-Comercial-76.png
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (120) - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal      (218) - Securing GET /comunes/imagenes/logoappname.png
 org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession    (189) - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (109) - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (120) - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation    (210) - Authorized filter invocation [GET /comunes/imagenes/logoappname.png] with attributes [permitAll]
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter      (333) - Secured GET /comunes/imagenes/logoappname.png
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (120) - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal      (218) - Securing GET /faces/asset/img/favicon.ico
 org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession    (189) - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (109) - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2Authentication [Principal=196934, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=remoteAddress=10.109.32.6, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearer, tokenValue=<TOKEN>, Granted Authorities=[]]]
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation    (210) - Authorized filter invocation [GET /faces/asset/img/favicon.ico] with attributes [authenticated]
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter      (333) - Secured GET /faces/asset/img/favicon.ico
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter      (120) - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Comment: could you please enable spring security debug logging and post the logs here in full.

Comment: @Toerktumlare, this part of log that (218) - Securing GET /
 (104) - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
 (100) - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
 (116) - Request requested invalid session id 18C593A6BA3973FAB774F403A0B75567.principal_acc_gen02
 (210) - Authorized filter invocation [GET /] with attributes [permitAll]
 (333) - Secured GET /
 (360) - Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
 (360) - Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
 (120) - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 (218) - Securing GET /securedPage

Comment: please dont post logs in comments, its completely unreadable, Stack Overflow is not a forum. Update your question using the edit button with the full logs formatted.

Comment: sorry I new, i try to load the output of the debug. @Toerktumlare

Comment: i dont see anything in the logs about `Too many redirects`

Comment: the Too many redirects appear in the client browser, for a few seconds and then the app show the page without issue

Comment: well its not a spring problem

Comment: Ok thanks @Toerktumlare , but what could be the reason of this behaviour. if just change tomcat 9.050 to 9.0.71.